# Merging multiple databases as separate schemas in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have to combine data from 4 different databases. Each having its own design.

What i want to do is to Create a new database with my desired schema. and one schema per (to be merged) database

Then export tables from all other databases and import this data into a unique corresponding schemas schema inside my final database.

How do i export table data from Postgresql Databases.

After having one database with multiple schemas i will use cross schema queries to read and write data to target schema.

Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 2):

I would assume that the other databases are Postgres as well? And all of them have only one schema? If you only have to do it once, then the easiest way is to use `pg_dump -Fc` to export the database and then edit the resulting SQL file by some regexp script.

In detail, you will have a

```
SET search_path = public;
```

row near the top of the file.  Rewrite 'public' to the desired schema name.  Other places to check for are where a stored procedure returns a user-defined type, view or table rowtype, here you will see something similar to

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f()
RETURNS public.my_view AS
...
```

Rewrite 'public' in such places as well.

Comment: I think editing isn't necessary. To dump schemas from databases use `pg_dump` with `-n` option and restore them into desired database. If you want large objects to be included in the dump take a look at `-b` option.

Comment: The most likely scenario is that the 4 separate databases all make use of the public schema, and so you will need to modify the schema names before loading them into the new database. If by chance they all use unique schema names inside the source databases, then your right, no edit will be neccessary. But it seems likely the edit would be needed.

Answer (score -1):

To export/import data you can use `COPY FROM / COPY TO`. Details [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html).

Or you can use dblink to query data in other database. Details [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/dblink.html).

Comment: @martin, @Wojtas 
Hi,Many thanks for your responses. Yes all the databases are on the same PostgreSQL server, and also have only one schema. I did the following steps.
`1. pg_dump -h 192.168.64.183 -p 5432 -U user -i -F t -v -f "/home/user/DB1.public" -n 'public' DB1`
`2. pg_restore -d DBTARGET -F t -L /home/user/DB1.public -i -n publicee2 -S user -X disable-triggers`

Are these the correct steps?